Python. Editing and downloading Google Sheets to PDF
I have a Google spreadsheet. It has 4 sheets.
I want the user to be able to enter any text in the python console, it will be inserted into a specific cell in the table, and then this sheet will be sent to the user in PDF format. Is this possible?
haven't done anything yet

yes, it's possible. You can find a python based tutorial here to get you started. Give it a try!
